# Recalling function on same input causing loops

Tags: javascript, linked-list

Wrote the below function to merge two linkedlists:

```
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    current = l1.head;    
    if (current === null){
        l1.head = l2.head; //Have to use l1.head instead of current since if we assign current again to l2.head the current will just start pointing to l2.head and lose reference to l1.
    }    
    else{        
        while( current.next != null){            
            current = current.next;            
        }        
        current.next = l2.head;        
    }    
    return l1;
};
```

Creating two linked lists:

```
let l1 = new linkedlist();
let l2 = new linkedlist();
l1.insert(1);
l1.insert(2);
l1.insert(4);
l2.insertEnd(1);
l2.insertEnd(3);
l2.insertEnd(4);
```

Now i called the function twice:

```
let l3 = mergeTwoLists(l1,l2);
console.log(l3.show());
let l4 = mergeTwoLists(l1,l2);
console.log(l4.show())
```

The first show outputs the expected 4 2 1 1 3 4. However, the second call goes on an infinite loop and keeps outputting 4 2 1 1 3 4 1 3 4 1 3 4 1 3 4 ........

Why is this happening?

Answer (score -1):

`mergeTwoLists` doesn't make copies of the list nodes. So after the first merge, the last node of `l1` is the same as the last node of `l2`. When you merge them again, the `next` property of the last node in `l2` now points to `l2.head`, resulting in a circular list, just as if you'd done `mergeTwoLists(l2, l2)`.

If you don't want this to happen, you should define a `copyList()` function, and use

```
current.next = copyList(l2).head;
```